# Target specific instance of class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to remove a class from a specific instance of a div with a specific class that a user clicks. For example, i have three instances of a class, let's say `unread`, i then want to remove a class from this instance of the div. It's probably a really simple solution, but cannot find an answer anywhere.

I tried using `$(this)` but apparently that doesn't work, it still removes the class from all instances of unread.

The user will basically click the div and it will mark their message as read and thus add a new class that shows the user visually that they have read the message.

HTML

```
<div class="sidebar bottom-sidebar mb15mob">        
    <h2 class="nmb">Debate Updates <span class="close-sidebar close-bottom-sidebar visible-xs visible-sm"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span></h2>
    <div class="mark-read">MARK ALL AS READ</div>

    <ul class="step no-list-icon">
        <li class="unread">
        <h3>Obamacare</h3>
        <p>I'm not entirely sure i agree with your sentiments there. I personally belie...</p>
        </li>
        <li class="unread">
        <h3>Obamacare</h3>
        <p>I'm not entirely sure i agree with your sentiments there. I personally belie...</p>
        </li>
        <li>
        <h3>Zombie Invasion</h3>
        <p>How can you be so sure that the government hasn't put aside money for the eventu...</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

jQuery

The below code removes all instances of unread, obviously, but i only want to remove the one clicked instance of the class. Hope that makes sense.

```
$(".unread").click(function () {
$(".step.no-list-icon li").removeClass("unread-debate-message");
});
```

Comment: What is the code you tried and does not work?

Comment: I didn't add it, since i'm particularly novice with Javascript and jQuery and anything that i may have tried would probably be completely wrong anyway. I assumed it would be an easy question to answer so didn't add my attempts so far - do you think it's necessary that i re-write it to add to my original post? Will do that if so.

Comment: Could you at least show your HTML, explain what the user does/will-do and *when* this 'specific instance of class' element should be affected? And to what end? As for your claim that "*apparently [`$(this)`] doesn't work, it still adds the class to all instances...*" that depends entirely upon the context within which you call `$(this)` and what `$(this)` (and `this`) are at that point.

Comment: @NikkiMather If you posted your code, we could see what your flaw was...Just edit the question and add it.

Comment: Is your JS something like `$(".unread").on("click", function () { $(this).addClass("read"); });`? Is that what "doesn't work"?

Comment: Thanks! Now, add the jQuery that you're shy about posting; we may criticize (but hopefully in a constructive manner), but we're not going to ridicule you for getting it wrong or for misunderstanding: *we all started somewhere, once upon a time.* Should a class (for example `read`) be *added* and/ or should the `unread` class be removed?

Comment: Added the HTML and jQuery. I kinda feel retarded posting code that i know is wrong - by the way, the jQuery is what i currently have (the one that remove all instances of unread). I actually asked my question somewhat wrong - it's 1am and i'm losing the plot ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your posted jQuery, the solution seems to be as simple as:

```
// selects all the elements of class "unread", and binds a click event-handler:
$(".unread").click(function () {
    // this/$(this) will always be the item that was interacted with:
    $(this).removeClass("unread");
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Rhhqj/1/).

In order to ensure the clicked elements are of the right type (to make sure the anonymous function doesn't remain bound once the class-name is removed, because the events are bound to the DOM node *not* to the DOM node(s) with that class-name), you could instead use delegated event-handling, binding the click-detection/handling to the parent element and supplying a selector it must match:

```
// selecting the elements with the 'unread' class-name:
$(".unread")
// moving to their closest 'ul' ancestor element(s):
.closest('ul')
// using 'on()' to bind a click event-handler to that ancestor,
// the anonymous function will be triggered only if the clicked-element
// matches the selector (the second string):
.on('click', '.unread', function () {
    // removing the 'unread' class from the clicked-element:
    $(this).removeClass("unread");
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Rhhqj/2/).

References:

- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).

Comment: Spot on. Thanks David, i complicated things a lot when i tried writing it myself using `this`. Apologies for the ridiculous question, but the answer is appreciated none the less.

Comment: @Nikki: I'm glad to have been able to help, but *please*, in future, post the relevant code when you ask your question. Even, *especially*, if it's broken: *show us* that you tried, and made an attempt. Even if only to provide an insight into what you're trying to do.

Comment: Do note that this handler stays attached even after the class is removed, so if you're doing some other stuff in the handler (eg. `alert('Clicked .unread element')`), you might want to consider delegation.

Comment: @Asad: agreed, I've since edited to add that delegation solution. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: David, i'm not sure whether it's worthy of an entire new question, but how would `this` work in regards to showing and hiding specific instances of a clicked div? The code i have currently is `$(".close-textarea").click(function () { $(".reply-with-textarea").show(); $(".reply-textarea").hide(); });`, but i only want to show and hide the specific instances of these divs that are inside the clicked instance of `close-textarea`. At the moment, it shows and hides all instances on the page.

Comment: @NikkiMather This is not difficult to answer, but it would be worthy of a new question, since it is an entirely separate topic. However, before you post a new question, please do some googling and look around on SO to see if you can't find the answer yourself.

Comment: I second @Asad's suggestion on this. Partially because it's (almost) two in the morning, and I think I should go to sleep now...sorry! :)